# custom primary key in Laravel not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I've set a custom primary key in my Task.php model.

```
class Task extends Model
{
    //

    protected $primaryKey = 'taskn';
    public $incrementing = false;

}
```

I've also set `taskn` as my primary key in the migration:

```
$table->string('taskn');

$table->primary('taskn');
```

But I still get the error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Task` where `id` = 1 limit 1)
```

For some reason Laravel still tries to query `id`.

I am trying to retrieve the data with the following call:

```
$tasks = DB::table('tasks')->find($taskn);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you do this bit? "If your primary key is not an integer, you should set the protected `$keyType` property on your model to string."

Comment: @ceejayoz No, I didn't. I tried it now, but same result :(

Comment: What's the code that's generating the error? Are you sure you're not doing something like `whereId()` instead of `find()` somewhere?

Comment: I see the error in my browser when I open the URL. I'm doing `$tasks = DB::table('tasks')->find($taskn);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm doing `$tasks = DB::table('tasks')->find($taskn);`

Here's your problem.

`DB::` calls don't use Eloquent - you're completely bypassing it. If you do `Task::find($taskn)` it'll work, but `DB::` calls have no idea about your `$primaryKey` settings.

Comment: That sounds like a good explanation! I'll fix that immediately. Do you know by chance how to search for a different primary key when using `DB::`calls?

Comment: @alev Just do `DB::table('tasks')->where('taskn', $taskn)->first()` for that.

Comment: @alev, why would you use DB calls like this when you have an Eloquent model?  Seems strange.

Comment: @Devon: I'm new to Laravel and first mixed up both of the methods. Once I learned from ceejayoz that there is a difference I just wanted to fully understand both capabilities. I'm sure it is handy to know. I agree, going forward using the Eloquent model is the nicer way.